# Audio Capture throws exception in Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am using the following JAVA methods to capture Audio before transmitting to the other end using Sockets.

```
private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
     float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
     int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
     int channels = 1;
     boolean signed = true;
     boolean bigEndian = false;
     return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels,
           signed, bigEndian);
  }

  private void captureAudio() throws Exception {
     try {
        System.out.println("Capturing audio........");
        AudioFormat audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
              TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        Mixer mixer = null;
        System.out.println("Available mixers:");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
           mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);
           if (mixer.isLineSupported(dataLineInfo)) {
              System.out.println(mixerInfo[cnt].getName());
              targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer
                    .getLine(dataLineInfo);
           }
        }
        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();

        while (true) {
           int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                 tempBuffer.length);
           System.out.println("Read buffer......."+cnt);
           out.write(tempBuffer);
           out.flush();
        }


     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;
     }
  }
```

But when I ran the full code on Raspberry Pi 2 model B, it throws java.lang.NullPointerException while referring to lines invoking captureAudio() and targetDataLine.open(audioFormat).

Is it because my capturing device is not properly installed on Raspberry Pi OR is it related to bigEndian Issue?